# SELinux is blocking getty from reading /etc/issue

Tags: linux, selinux

I recently changed my hostname, and after rebooting with the new hostname, /etc/issue stopped getting displayed on the login screen. I disabled selinux temporarily, and /etc/issue was displayed again. After re-enabling selinux, /etc/issue once again stopped displaying. Can anyone tell me what's going on and how to fix it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the easiest way is disabling SELinux, which I don't recommend, though:

```
setenforce 0
```

Or you can create a rule to allow it to write, run or whatever it needs to do and is being blocked so far. To do so, check your system log file and copy the line that is "denied", it should be something like this:

```
audit(...): avc:  denied  { write } for  pid=27984 comm="hostname" name="hostname" dev=sda6 ino=307469 scontext=root:system_r:system_r:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:usr_t:s0 tclass=...
```

Copy it and run the following command:

```
audit2allow -M local << _EOF_
(paste the content)
_EOF_
```

Then, run:

```
semodule -i local.pp
```

That will create a permanent rule for it so you shouldn't need to disable SELinux. Even if you have more than one `denied` line, you can paste all of them at once and `audit2allow` will generate as many rules as you need in your `local.pp` file.

Comment: This way actually prevents from having the AVC denied, however, it doesn't answer the question "why did the file get a bad context?". 

First : ls -lZ /etc/issue
and check in audit log for exact AVC message. 
Then change the file context using restorecon or chcon to match the expected SELinux context.

Comment: I like your answer, but I know very little about SELinux.  What is -lZ?